# IInternet Explorer 7 problems loading JW player

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, jwplayer

I created a website and used the JW Player to stream videos. The videos are playing fine in chrome, Firefox and opera but the videos are not playing on internet explorer 7 and mobile devices like Android and iPads and iPhones. What could be the problem? my code is here

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    jwplayer("jwplayer-1").setup({
        "flashplayer": "http://url.net/player/player.swf",
        "width": "660",
        "height": "420",
        "controlbar": "bottom",
        "dock": "false",
        "autostart": "false",
        "icons": "true",
        "playlist.position": "none",
        "playlistsize": "180",
        "repeat": "none",
        "shuffle": "false",
        "bufferlength": "1",
        "smoothing": "true",
        "stretching": "uniform",
        "wmode": "opaque",
        "mute": "false",
        "volume": "90",
        "plugins": "adtimage",
        "adtimage.graphic": "http://url.net/default_ad.png",
        "adtimage.link": "mailto:mail@gmail.com",
        "adtimage.positions": "pre,post",
        "adtimage.onpause": "true",
        "adtimage.txt": "Advertisement",
        "adtimage.btntxt": "Click to continue with video",
        "file": "http://url.net/music/private/File.flv",
        "image": "http://url.net/thumb.jpg",
        "provider": "video",
        "modes": [{
            "type": "html5",
            "config": {
                "streamer": "",
                "provider": "",
                "file": "private/File.flv"
            }
        }, {
            "type": "flash",
            "src": "http://url.net/player/player.swf"
        }, {
            "type": "download",
            "config": {
                "streamer": "",
                "provider": ""
            }
        }]
    });

</script>
```

the error being showed is this one 
`FLV à onMetaData duration@k“ =p£×width@”height@†€ videodatarate@±” framerate@7ùÜ videocodecid@ audiodatarate@` and some other stuff I don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your code and remove your private URLs.

I also added this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
```

And now try doing this:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
```

And also try defining fully (px)

```
"width": "660px",
"height": "420px",
```

Answer (score 1):

The charset attribute is only for external scripts (can only be used if the src attribute is present)
I hope it can be useful, D